# After flushing cache images disappear

Tags: caching, media

I've recently had to restore a website after a server crash. I have the majority of the website back up and running.

The problem comes when I flush the cache or disable a module. Images that were being displayed become missing. Looking at Chromes inspector it appears Drupal is looking in the wrong location.

Instead of looking in `sites/default/files/styles/footer_blog/public/blog_images?itok=_ZPwwAOU` it's looking in `sites/default/files/styles/footer_blog/public/?itok=_ZPwwAOU`. The images doesn't appear in the edit form either, although I know it's in the directory (`sites/default/files/styles/footer_blog/public/blog_images`)

The only thing that seems to cure it, is to restore the database but again when I flush the cache the same problem arises.

**More Details**

I appear to get the following error also

`Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in theme_image_formatter()` in the file `modules/image/image.field.inc` line `605`

Comment: Have you configured your files directory to be writable by your web server?

Comment: Yes, the permissions are currently 777

Comment: Sometimes it happens when the sub-folders under files directory are not writeable. We mostly use following command to make sure files folder and sub-folders are writeable, chmod -R 777 files

Comment: Thanks @amitgoyal, I've tried that and it still appears to happen

Comment: Did you get Drupal core and modules and themes from backup or did you download new ones? If you downloaded, did you get the newest versions and ran update.php?

Comment: Is the temp directory in admin/config/media/file-system set correctly? Does the status report say anything about that?

Comment: Do you already find a solution for this problem?